# How to detect the main page url from within a pluggable protocol handler

Tags: internet-explorer

I am implementing a [pluggable protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28VS.85%29.aspx#About_Pluggable_Name) in my own browser application for the purpose of blocking ads. It's a namespace handler to be exact. I can easily get the url of the element being dowloaded from within the namespace handler. But I would like to get the URL of the page which contains the element as well. The browser app I am building hosts many web browser controls in a single process. At this moment, I don't know any way to tell which web browser control issues the download request.

Thanks a lot for any useful tips leading to the solution.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I was about to ask the same question.  In my case it is for HTML email, and "cid:" URLs are not unique.  Would be nice to know which WebBrowser control is doing the loading.

Answer (score 0):

Using GetBindString in iinternetprotocolroot start will give you the url of the page.

```
pIBindInfo->GetBindString(BINDSTRING_URL, .., .., ..);
```

Comment: If only this worked :(  BINDSTRING_ROOTDOC_URL will probably work, for the "root" document as Stephen (and I) is looking for, but that is only IE9+ so will not work on XP.